# Remove Runner in xcode

Tags: flutter, xcode14

I have asked to remove Runner from my laptop (mac M1). I found that it is a part of xcode.
I'm implementing a flutter application and testing it in the xcode simulator (because Android emulator is very slow and some times get stuck).

If I removed Runner from my laptop, will there be any controversies to testing the app in the iphone simulator?

your input is much appreciated.